# Extract the last element and add it to the end in list by changing a property value

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0

I have a list like this

**CustomerSearch.cs**

```
int id;
string searchedWord;
```

If for example, if this **result** is like this

```
[
 {id: 1, searchedWord :"test"}
 {id: 2, searchedWord: "news"}
]
```

I am trying to copy the last element in the list and append to the existing list and increment the id number value.

The expected result is

```
[
 {id: 1, searchedWord :"test"}
 {id: 2, searchedWord: "news"}
 {id: 3, searchedWord: "news"}
]
```

I could do this way

```
CustomerSearch customerSearch=new CustomerSearch();
customerSearch.Id=result.ElementAt(result.Count()-1).Id;
customerSearch.SearchedWord=result.ElementAt(result.Count()-1).SearchedWord;

List<CustomerSearch> newResult=new List<CustomerSearch>();
foreach(var mycustomerSearch in result)
{
 newResult.Add(mycustomerSearch);
}
newResult.Insert(1, customerSearch);
newResult.ElementAt(2).Id=3;
```

I don't think, this is the optimal way, if there is a better way to do this, please share it, thanks. We can create the expected result as a new list or with that existing list.

Comment: What is the type of the variable `result`? Do you want to create a new list (`as in your sample`) or add a new item to an existing `result` list?

Comment: If `result` is json, you can just add a new token to it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you may modify the original list `result`:

```
CustomerSearch customerSearch = new CustomerSearch {
  Id = result.Last().Id + 1,
  SearchedWord = result.Last().SearchedWord
};

result.Add(customerSearch);
```

- Use Linq [`Last()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.last?view=netcore-3.1) to access the last element of `result`.
- Use [Object Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer) to initialize the new element nicely.

If you may not modify `result`:

```
CustomerSearch customerSearch = new CustomerSearch {
  Id = result.Last().Id + 1,
  SearchedWord = result.Last().SearchedWord
};

List<CustomerSearch> newResult = result.Select(x => x).ToList();

newResult.Add(customerSearch);
```

- Use Linq [`Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1) followed by [`ToList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netcore-3.1) to clone the original list.

Note that `Last()` throws an exception if `result` is null or empty. To protect against this, the above operation should be preceded by a check for those cases:

```
if (results == null || !results.Any())
{
  // handle in some way, perhaps by returning.
}
```

- Use Linq [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-3.1) to check if `result` is empty.

Comment: `Last()` throw an exception, when there is no items in list

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski True, but in the specific case stated in the question there are elements in the list. I added a note for the general case, though.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski IS this answered?